# Identify ranges of integers and group them by their start and end points

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Let's say I have a dataset with one column (IDNUMBER) that looks like this:

```
IDNUMBER
1
2
3
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
```

I would ideally like to have the whatever data exists in this column separated into two columns representing ranges of consecutive values.

```
START, END
1, 3
1001, 1005
```

I can do this with a cursor or a loop, but is there a set-based solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic Gaps-and-Islands

**Example**

```
Select [Start] = min(IDNUMBER)
      ,[End]   = max(IDNUMBER)
 From (    
        Select *
              ,Grp = IDNUMBER - Row_Number() over (Order by IDNUMBER)
         from YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Start   End
1       3
1001    1005
```

---

To help you visualize this, the subquery generates the following

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You beat me to it by only a couple of minutes. The answer in my code is almost the same, but I'm leaving the answer up because I elaborated on the whys behind the concept. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a number that increments by one with every record. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` should work. That way, you are subtracting your IDNUMBER from this incrementing number. As IDNUMBER increments by 1, so does ROWNUMBER. Therefore, the result `DataGroup` will be equal to the same integer as long as there are no breaks in the groupings.

Therefore, you make a subquery with that value and you now have a unique group ID to conveniently group on.

```
SELECT MIN(IDNUMBER), MAX(IDNUMBER) 
FROM (SELECT IDNUMBER, IDNUMBER - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IDNUMBER) AS DataGroup FROM MyTable)
GROUP BY DataGroup
ORDER BY DataGroup
```